# Blocked by CORS policy : Calling Azure Static Web App Azure Funcion from Browser

Tags: azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I've an **Azure Function inside Azure Static Web App** to fetch the Static Web App's Application Settings. While calling the Http Triggered Function URL through Code, from browser I'm getting -

*"Access to fetch at 'https://agreeable-rock-0ba5f3a10.1.azurestaticapps.net/' from origin 'http://localhost:44388' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled".*

**My Http Triggered Function Here**
[image]

**My Http Client Call to Function resides inside Azure Static Web App**

[image]

2 Projects I have. 1) Client is a MAUI App. 2) Azure Function. I've deployed Function as /Api in AzureStaticWebApp & Trying to access Application Settings from Client. Directly calling the FunctionURL from Postman, I'm able to get the Application Settings but not from Localhost-Browser.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add your code as text?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Function API linked to the Static Web App has CORS enabled to only *allow requests originating* from the Azure Static Web App domain for security purposes. As such, it would not be possible to access the Azure Functions from another domain (such as **localhost**:44388).

When developing locally, it is recommended that you instead call the `/api` `(localhost:44388/api)` route using the SWA CLI, as outlined in this doc: [Set up local development for Azure Static Web Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/local-development#how-it-works)

Just to clarify, could you let us know the purpose of the function app to retrieve the application settings? Is this for dev/test purposes or prod purposes? Please do share more details about your requirement.

Further, just to highlight, the [App settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#application-settings) and connection strings are stored encrypted in Azure. They're decrypted only before being injected into your app's process memory when the app starts.

Checkout similar discussion thread: [CORS on API portion of Azure Static Web Apps #108](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/108)

Comment: I'm using `swa` command: but get this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4280/api/myFunction' from origin 'http://localhost:4280' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.` When I open `localhost:4280`, it actually loads JS application. When I open `localhost:4280/api/myFunction`, it actually gives me data. So I'm confused, why is it not working, since both API and Frontend on the same host.